# MVVM pattern in Xamarin login form

Tags: c#, authentication, mvvm, xaml, xamarin

Please let me know if the MVVM pattern I followed in this is correct or not.

Here is the code for *ViewModel*

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";



    public ProgressBar ProgressBar { get; set; }
    public Label StatusLabel { get; set; }

    public Command LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async()=> {
                ProgressBar.IsVisible = true;
                ProgressBar.Progress = 0;
                await ProgressBar.ProgressTo(0.2, 250, Easing.BounceOut);


                if(Email.Length>0 && Password.Length > 0)
                {
                    ApiServices apiServices = new ApiServices();
                    var isSuccess = await apiServices.LoginAsync(Email, Password);
                    if (isSuccess)
                    {
                        await ProgressBar.ProgressTo(1, 250, Easing.Linear);
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new FirstMasterDetailPage();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await ProgressBar.ProgressTo(1, 250, Easing.Linear);
                        StatusLabel.IsVisible = true;
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Failed to login.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await ProgressBar.ProgressTo(1, 250, Easing.Linear);
                    StatusLabel.IsVisible = true;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Username and Password is required to login.";
                }
                ProgressBar.IsVisible = false;
            });
        }
    }

    public Command RegisterCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(()=> {
                Application.Current.MainPage = new RegisterPage();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this is code behind page

```
public LoginPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var current = BindingContext as LoginViewModel;
        current.ProgressBar = progressBar;
        current.StatusLabel = lblStatus;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

1. View-model shouldn't contain anything related to view. It means `LoginViewModel` shouldn't contain references on progress bar and label. `ProgressBar` and `Label` properties inside a view-model violate MVVM.
2. Any changes in UI elements should be done via bindings specified in XAML. Those bindings have to be linked to properties of a view-model. Changing these properties, UI get updated.
3. To make bindings work you should notify them about changes in view-model. For that purpose you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the view-model and raise `PropertyChanged` event every time a property changed.

Let's see example of how you can remove `ProgressBar` from the `LoginViewModel`.

First of all, view -model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface which contains `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then remove `ProgressBar` property and add `LoginInProgress`:

```
private bool _loginInProgress;

public bool LoginInProgress
{
    get => _loginInProgress;
    set
    {
        if (value == _loginInProgress)
            return;

        _loginInProgress = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LoginInProgress)));
    }
}
```

Now in the `LoginCommand` body instead of

> ```
> ProgressBar.IsVisible = true;
> ```

write

```
LoginInProgress = true;
```

And instead of

> ```
> ProgressBar.IsVisible = false;
> ```

write

```
LoginInProgress = false;
```

Then in XAML bind `Visibility` of the `progressBar` to this property:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar"
             Visibility="{Binding Path=LoginInProgress, Mode=OneWay, Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}"}"
             .../>
```

Somewhere in resources you should define `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

And that's all. You need to eliminate all the view related stuff from the view model in such way. It is how MVVM have to be implemented.

Comment: can you suggest me what's the correct way of writing ViewModel for this class @Maxim

Comment: @Siraj I agree with my learned friend Maxim also - why not set the command property with a method called from the LoginViewModel constructor rather than using an anonymous function - because you'll be instantiating every time the command property is called? secondly why not also post your XAML as well - because data binding to properties exposed by your ViewModel class is essential to the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: @Siraj I've added an example of how you can implement MVVM correctly.